# Python multilevel inheritence

Tags: python, inheritance

```
class A:  
    def foo(self):  
        print("original")  
class B(A):  
    def foo(self):  
        super().foo()  
        print("override")  
class C(B):  
    def foo(self):
      super().foo()
       print("override")

o = c()
```

Now after defining this object, I want to, access the foo of class A through same object, how do I do that???

Comment: `BaseClass.function`. It's important that you share the context of why you want to do this, it may be a bad idea.

Comment: just trying to learn it and why it can be a bad idea???

Comment: @Vaibhav: Because selectively calling a specific super-class's version of a function indicates you likely have a flaw in your design. If calling *any* super-class's version of a function makes sense, then calling *all* of them (uniquely, via cooperative MRO traversal with `super`) is usually the correct thing to do. For example, if class `C` inherits from `B` which inherits from `A`, but `C` only wants to invoke `A`'s super-class method, that's a strong indication that `C` should inherit directly from `A`, not from `B`, and possibly that `B` shouldn't be a child of `A` at all.

Comment: To be clear, in *multiple* inheritance scenarios this might be necessary/semi-reasonable, e.g. because unrelated `ParentA` and `ParentB` classes might share a method with a coincidentally overlapping name, and `Child` is logically inheriting behavior from only one (hopefully the other behavior is exposed in some other way). But multiple inheritance is a minefield in itself (in general, aside from mix-in methods with no state, it's a trap), and your scenario doesn't match that scenario, making it much more likely to be a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually want to bypass all the child class implementations, just name the base class explicitly, e.g. replace:

```
self.method_name()  # Calls own class (or first parent with implementation if own class lacks it)
super().method_name()  # Call first parent class with implementation of the method
```

with:

```
GrandparentClass.method_name(self)  # Explicitly calls specific class's version of the method with self
```

To be clear, `GrandparentClass` is a placeholder for the actual name of the top-level class you want to call, it's not a special name/function like `super()`.

Note: If you're doing this, [you likely have an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040) that should probably be solved instead.

Answer (score 0):

> So now if I want to access that function with the same name from sub-subclass, of the base class, how do I do it???

`super().<method_name>(<params>)` is how you call a method "in the parent class" in order to delegate upwards.

```py
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print("original")
class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        super().foo()
        print("override")
```

Calling `B().foo()` will print "original" then "override".

Comment: no, if B has a subclass of it, let's say that c, and it has another function foo, and I am trying to access foo of the base class, that's A, through a function then how do I do it???